# Unique decomposition of wffs when left and right parentheses are indistinguishable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm working through Enderton's book *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic 2nd Edition* for self study.

Section 1.3 Exercise 7

Suppose that left and right parentheses are indistinguishable. Thus,
instead of (α∨(β∧γ)) we have

|α∨|β∧γ||. Do formulas still
have unique decomposition?

He is referring to the wffs (well formed formulas) I think. I'm trying to understand either why it has a unique decomposition through a proof, or why it doesn't through a counterexample or proof. So far I have not been able to come up with a counterexample so I have tried to develop an algorithm.

1. The first parenthesis will be treated as a left parenthesis.
2. Scan for the next parenthesis.

   - If it is immediately preceded by a binary connective, then it is a left parenthesis.
   - If it is immediately preceded by a sentence symbol, it is a right parenthesis.
   - If it is immediately preceded by a parenthesis, it is the same type as the preceding parenthesis.

However, I am not sure how to prove if it is correct and I am now stuck.

Comment: I don't understand what it means for a formula to have a unique decomposition. Can you please explain?

Comment: @GitGud: I think ignoramus is talking about 'unique readability'.

Comment: @KyleGannon I see. Thanks.

Comment: OP, if this is the case, then you can just try to copy the proof for the usual unique readability theorem. Copy the proof from [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Unique_Readability_Theorem_of_Propositional_Logic) to a text editor, use the replace function to replace `(` and `)` with `|` and you're done.

Comment: Shouldn't the expression be $|a \lor | \beta \land \gamma ||$?

Comment: @GitGud Ah ok. I read the proof you linked and also the _Initial Part of WFF of PropLog is not WFF_ proof. So it seems to me that the reason that the proof works for the case of `|` is that the distinguishability of the parentheses has no bearing on the validity of the proof. Is my interpretation correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes that is what it says in the question. The first `|` is at the end of the preceding line.

Comment: @ignoramus: My apologies, my eyes were playing tricks on me.

Comment: Your algorithm implies that the third parenthesis in |α∨|β∧γ|| is a left parenthesis, since the third "|" is preceded by ∧.  You would do better to say "immediately preceded by".

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Ah yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @ignoramus That's right.

Comment: @ignoramus No problem. I'd prefer if you posted an answer. In my opinion an ideal answer would include a proof of [*Initial Part of WFF of PropLog is not WFF*](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Initial_Part_of_WFF_of_PropLog_is_not_WFF) and a proof of the unique readability theorem.

Comment: @GitGud I added another proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Proof that WFFs with indistinguishable parentheses have unique decomposition/readability

(Credit to GitGud, ProofWiki)

**Theorem 1**

Let **A** be a WFF of propositional logic.
Let **S** be an initial part of **A**.
Then **S** is not a WFF of propositional logic.

**Proof**
Let *l*(**Q**) denote the length of a string **Q**.

By definition, **S** is an initial part of **A** iff **A=ST** for some non-null string **T**.

Thus we note that *l*(**S**)**<***l*(**A**).

Let **A** be a WFF such that *l*(**A**)=1

Then for an initial part **S**, *l*(**S**)<1=0.

That is, **S** must be the null string, which is not a WFF.

So the result holds for WFFs of length 1.

Now, we assume an induction hypothesis: that the result holds for all WFFs of length *k* or less.

Let **A** be a WFF such that *l*(**A**)=*k+1*.

Suppose **D** is an initial part of **A** which happens to be a WFF.

That is, **A=DT** where **T** is non-null.

There are two cases:

- **A=¬B**, where **B** is a WFF of length *k*. **D** is a WFF starting with ¬, so **D=¬E** where **E** is also a WFF. We remove the initial ¬ from **A=DT** to get **B=ET**. But then **B** is a WFF of length *k* which has **E** as an initial part which is itself a WFF. This contradicts the induction hypothesis. Therefore no initial part of **A=¬B** can be a WFF.
- **A=**|**B**∘**C**| where ∘ is one of the binary connectives. In this case, **D** is a WFF starting with |, so **D**=|**E**∗**F**| for some binary connective ∗ and some WFFs **E** and **F**. Thus **B**∘**C**|=**E**∗**F**|**T**. Both **B** and **E** are WFFs of length less than *k+1*. By the inductive hypothesis, then, neither **B** nor **E** can be an initial part of the other. But since both **B** and **E** start at the same place in **A**, they must be the same: **B=E**. Therefore **B∘C|=B∗F|T**. So ∘=∗ and **C|=F|T**. But then the WFF **F** is an initial part of the WFF **C** of length less than *k+1*. This contradicts our inductive hypothesis. Therefore no initial part of **A=(B∘C)** can be a WFF.

So no initial part of any WFF of length *k+1* can be a WFF.

The result follows by strong induction.

**Theorem 2**

Each WFF of propositional logic which starts with a | or a negation sign has exactly one main connective.

Thus, on a higher level, there is only one way to interpret the semantics of a given WFF of propositional logic.

**Proof** There are two cases to consider.

Consider the case where **A=|B∘C|** for some WFFs **B** and **C** and some binary connective ∘.

Suppose also that **A=|D∗E|** where **D** and **E** are also WFFs, and ∗ is another binary connective.

The WFFs **B** and **D** are strings which both start in the same place, right after the first left | in **A**.

By Theorem 1, neither **B** nor **D** can be an initial part of the other.

Therefore **B=D**.

It follows that ∗=∘ and **C=E**.

Now consider the case where **A=¬B**.

The result follows directly from the definition of the main connective for a WFF of this form.

Hence the result.
■

Answer (score 0):

The proof given in the answer(using strong induction on length) is fine, but one can also prove this using only *structural* induction: prove using structural induction that for $|| \text{wffs}$(Here $||\text{wffs}$ denotes the wffs constructed with indistinguishable parentheses) the following property holds for any $||\text{wff}$, $ \phi:$

- "No proper initial sub-segment of $\phi$ is a $||\text{wff}$ nor is $\phi$ the proper initial sub-segment of any $|| \text{wff}$."